# Where does Google Music store offline songs?

Tags: storage, file-management, google-play-music

I have a song I want to use for a ringtone, but the Google Music app doesn't let me set it.  I've checked on my sdcard/internal storage for a music/google/gmusic etc folder but can't find anything.

Where is the music file stored on my phone?

Comment: See ["Where does Google Play Music v5 store music locally?"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51665/where-does-google-play-music-v5-store-music-locally) for the location of the new Google Music version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Google Music Apps cache is at

```
/<external_SD>/Android/data/com.google.android.music/cache/music
```

which is usually

```
/sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.music/cache/music
```

Comment: Is it possible that this folder is only readable on a rooted device? On my (unrooted) Nexus 4, using Astro File Manager, both the `/cache` and `/files` subfolders appear "EMPTY", even with "Show hidden files" enabled. (And I have quite a few songs available offline/"on device" within Google Play Music.)

Comment: I assume that this has to do something with the multi-user feature and new sdcard layout of Android 4.2. You can read more about it [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35541/why-did-sdcard-turn-into-sdcard-0-with-4-2) and [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39542/confused-by-the-many-locations-of-the-virtual-sdcard). tl;dr try looking at `/sdcard/0/...` or `/sdcard/<userid>/..`.

Comment: Well, maybe... but I have neither of those folders you mention. If I search the entire device for music/mp3 files (using Astro FM) the only files found are files I have manually copied onto the device. None of my "offline" (Google Play Music) music is found. Using the [DiskUsage app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en) I can see a large continuous data block in Apps/Google Play Music/ which appears to relate to my "offline" music (the size increases as I store more offline) - but there are no individual files as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually in `/data/data/com.google.android.music/files/music`.

You might need root to access this. The songs are titled just by numbers so it might be a pain to find the right ones. This is from a Sprint Samsung Galaxy S4 rooted stock ROM NAE Android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Bluetooth File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp) and have found the files in

```
/storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.google.android.music/files/music
```

I'm running Android 4.4.2 on a Galaxy S5 (not rooted) and the Play Music app is v5.7.1788Q.1634597