# Where does Google Music store the “offline tracks”?

Tags: rom-flashing, offline, google-play-music

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does Google Music store offline songs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16220/where-does-google-music-store-offline-songs)

I have about 8 gigs of music stored within Google Music, and I recently got sick of streaming (and risking data charges), so I painstakingly allowed it to be stored offline. So my fresh 16 gig SD card now only had 8 gigs left. Then, I flashed a new rom, thinking that all my music would still be there cached (or however it works), but I was wrong. When I click "show offline tracks only" within the Google Music app, it shows nothing, yet my SD card still only has 8 gigs of space left.

So, my question is, where are these offline tracks stored on my SD card so I can go in and delete them, to free up space so I can back them all up again?

Thanks!

And also, why won't the app recognize that there is offline music stored on my SD card after a new rom is flashed? I figured that data would be untouched across roms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your songs should get saved to `/sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.music/cache/music`.

The reason they don't appear when you install a new ROM is because the folder they're stored in contains a `.nomedia` file, which excludes it from the media scanner. Google Music is able to keep track of them because it puts entries into its database (which is at `/data/data/com.google.android.music/databases/music.db`) which point to the file. Specifically, anything in the `MUSIC` table with a `LocalCopyType` value of 200 is a song on Google's servers which you've downloaded so it will be "available offline". This disappears if you wipe your `/data` partition when flashing a new ROM. If you have a `sqlite3` binary on your device you can use the following to get a list of all songs that are available offline:

```
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.music/databases/music.db
sqlite> select * from music where localcopytype = 200;
```

If you want to have your music stored locally across ROM installs, the easiest thing to do is just to create a folder at the root of your SD card named `Music` (or similar) and put the files in it. The media scanner will pick it up that way. Alternatively, you can try removing the `.nomedia` file from the Google Music cache folder. That should allow it be scanned, too, but I don't know if Google Music will try to re-create the file on subsequent launches of the app.

Comment: Okay thanks. But when I wipe /data does it delete the actual files I've downloaded or just the pointers to them? I just don't want unaccessible songs taking up precious space haha

Comment: @roboguy12: No, it only wipes the app's database, and therefore all of its entries. The files themselves are on the SD card in the folder I noted above. You can simply delete them with a file explorer or from your computer by plugging in your phone and accessing it as a USB storage device.

Comment: The only problem is when I go into /sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.music/cache/music, the only files that are in there are the 4 most recent songs I've listened to, not my entire 8 gig library.

Comment: @roboguy12: That's strange, I've never seen them stored anywhere else. What version of Google Music do you have and what kind of phone is it?

Comment: It's a Droid Incredible, running a stock 2.3.7 rom...the app is Music v4.1.512. And just to test it out, I went into the app and checked a few random songs to be available offline to try to find them on the SD card and they weren't in cache/music...nor could I find them anywhere on the SD Card.

Comment: @roboguy12: Well, I guess one way to figure out what it's doing would be to query the music database. It stores the path to the file as one of the columns in the `MUSIC` table, so the query I noted above should show you where they are. That's how I found the folder on my device initially.

Comment: This might be grounds for a different question, but I "adb shell" and then run that command and it says sqlite3: not found. What does this mean? If I should start another question, I can and then I'll post the link to that one here so you can answer it if you want.

Comment: Your ROM probably doesn't have the `sqlite3` binary. [SuperOneClick](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682) has a copy (in the "Dependencies" folder). You could push it onto your device with `adb` to use it ([this Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5022363/390989) has some instructions)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your device and app version it might also be `/data/data/com.google.android.music/files/music/`.

This, of course, is secure storage and only accessible to app itself. On an non-rooted phone that is.

Comment: Does "secure storage" mean that on an unrooted device the folder is visible, but the contents unreadable? I have quite a few music files stored offline, but Astro File Manager reports these folders as "EMPTY" even with "Show hidden files" enabled.