# Google Music Offline Tracks

Tags: google-play-music

I have sort of a follow-up question to [a question I asked a little while ago](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/where-does-google-music-store-the-offline-tracks)...
That question was naively asking where Google Music stores the offline tracks (I've come so far since then), but my question is now, when I navigate to that folder in a shell, it only shows 11 songs, all with numerical names? I understand the numerical naming method, and I `pulled` some of these songs to see what they were, but I have about 5 gigs of offline music. Where is the rest of it stored?

The reason I'm asking this is because I'm about to flash a new rom, and want to know that those songs will be accessible to the new Google Music app I install on the new rom. If not, I will first want to disable their offline storage to free up space on my SD Card and then just offline them again.

But anyway, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Finding out where it's stored is easy. There's a terrific little app called [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en) that visualizes the space your folders take up. You can easily spot where the Music cache is.

As for moving to a new rom. Based eldarerathis' answer to your previous question, you should be able to make a backup of Play Music's music.db either from a terminal or using an app like Titanium Backup. Restoring this file on the new rom *should* make cached music show up.

Comment: Thanks! This worked with the few tracks I tried it with, but in the end I just ended up making them all not available offline, flashed the new rom, and then made them available again. But I tested this just to see and it worked!