# How do I make JB use my external sd card (/storage/extSdCard)

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, app2sd, external-sd

I have a Samsung Note2 with 4.1.1 on it. I have what appears to be a virtual sd card called `/storage/sdcard0`. It uses phone memory. When I installed my new 32gb sdcard it was mounted as `/storage/extSdCard`.

The OS only seems to use sdcard0 for SD-like storage (like apps). I know this because SuperBox is reporting apps on my SDCard and they are really on `sdcard0`. The only way I can use my external card is if I tell some application to use it for storage.

Since `sdcard0` is just eating up precious phone RAM is there a way I can safely convince JB to start using `/storage/extSdCard` instead?

Comment: You are very funny: *sdcard0 is just eating up precious phone RAM* is a good joke!</irony> Sorry, but that **is** your sdcard (though the internal), but *not* RAM. See: [Why did /sdcard/ turn into /sdcard/0/ with 4.2?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35541/16575)

Comment: I do not have 4.2.  It really is based on RAM.  It cannot both be internal and an SD card.

Comment: sdcard0 is not using RAM, sdcard0, as @Izzy said is your internal storage that is available. /sdcard/ is just a symlink to /storage/sdcard0/. It IS considered "sdcard" because it is built in storage that acts just like sdcard, except it cannot be removed. You cannot use the internal storage for anything except what you would use a normal sdcard for.

Comment: It might be considered SD card, and the intention might be to use it like an sd card, but it isn't an SD card.  And the only place that it can come from is RAM.  That's the only storage available to it.  So again, I claim it is RAM.  And funnily enough, if you look at SuperBox, my Phone's RAM usage is tracking almost exactly with my /storage/sdcard0 usage.  I haven't found the fstab for it yet, but I bet if I do I'm going to find a RAM device mounted at location /storage/sdcard0 and then symlinked to /sdcard as well.

Comment: I think you confused RAM with internal flash storage (memory).

Comment: @Izzy, though OP confused RAM with internal storage, this is a very painful question. I'm facing the same right now with my GT-I9505 (AOSP 4.4.2). It uses emulated SD card instead of external and I have no idea on how to convince it to use the right one.

Comment: Umm... I knew we had this somewhere already. You might also wish to watch [How do I make /sdcard link point to external SD Card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/69127/16575)

Comment: @Izzy, yep, I started that =)

Comment: Ugh... nevermind. Shall we close one of the two as duplicate? #D

Comment: @Izzy, mine is about KitKat, so it's not quite a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you're rooted, a simple, though kinda brute force, solution is simply to swap the mount points around.  [Root External 2 Internal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.codlab.int2ext) will do this automatically at boot for you.  This app is strictly intended for the GS3, but reviews report success with the Note 2 also.