# /data and /storage/sdcard0 seems to refer to the same place? Why?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd

On my "8GB" device (which I believe doesn't have an extra physical sdcard installed (I have to unscrew it to see that)) I have the following df output:

```
Filesystem             Size   Used   Free   Blksize
/dev                   402M    32K   401M   4096
/mnt/secure            402M     0K   402M   4096
/mnt/asec              402M     0K   402M   4096
/mnt/obb               402M     0K   402M   4096
/mnt/shm              1024K     0K  1024K   4096
/system                503M   297M   206M   4096
/data                    6G   344M     5G   4096
/cache                 495M   186M   309M   1024
/device                  7M     1M     6M   1024
/storage/sdcard0         6G   344M     5G   4096
```

I am confused though, because /data and /storage/sdcard0 are exactly the same (suspiciously the same!), but as I understand it though: /storage/sdcard0 should refer to an external physical sd-card, and not refer to the same place as /data. What is going on?

Comment: For device without external physical storage, `/storage/sdcard/` still refers to external storage, but it's emulated. [This question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39542/confused-by-the-many-locations-of-the-virtual-sdcard) might be helpful, or even it might be a duplicate.

Comment: But then it should mount under /storage/emulated/ or something, no?

Comment: On my Nexus 7, `/storage/sdcard0` is a symlink to `/storage/emulated/0`. Your device probably has something similar. I don't think the exact mountpoint matters (i.e sdcard0 vs emulated/0), as long as they all point to the expected location.