# CWM Recovery showing wrong sdcard info

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode

So i have installed Cyanogenmod 10.2 using Clockworkmod Recovery, which went fine.

However now I am unable to get rid of CWMR. I tried flashing TWRM, but CWMR persists.

Even worse, CWMR shows the data on /sdcard from my old ROM. it is not up to the actual sdcard contents. and whenever i try to enter any directory it still shows the same data again. it's like going into a loop.

the only exception is, that when i enter the directory called "0" it shows the actual data of the new cyanogenmod installation.

is it possible that cyanogen actually installed itself into /sdcard/0 and the old data is still present in /sdcard/

this would explain why i am having only little space on my sdcard free.

Comment: Could it be the CM version installed is a little "higher" than the Android version you had before? Somewhere between ICS (Android 4.0) and JellyBean 4.2, directory structures for SDcard changed: instead of simply `/sdcard`, it's now `/sdcard/0` (to allow for multiple cards; see [Why did /sdcard/ turn into /sdcard/0/ with 4.2?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35541/16575)). There are storage problems reported concerning the migration, where a copy of the "old content" remained in `/sdcard`. That might be what happened to you here.

Comment: yes, this CM is now based on 4.2 whereas the old samsung os was based on 4.1. so does that mean, that the old data is still there? how can i get rid of it?

Comment: Delete it (e.g. using a file manager)? First make sure you copied everything you wanted to keep.

Comment: i cant see it in a filemanager. filemanagers seem to already show the contents of the /sdcard/0 only.the only place where i see it, is in CWMR mode.

Comment: What if you use a terminal app and do it from the command line? Alternatively, use ADB from your computer, in combination with a graphical frontend like [QtADB](https://qtadb.wordpress.com/).