# Difference between /mnt/sdcard and /sdcard

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, file-system

I'm in the beginning of Android kernel study and I'm looking at every directory in rooted Android.

I realized that the same directories were in those two: `/mnt/sdcard` and `/sdcard`. What's the difference between them?

(The directories that I found were:

Alarms,Android, Audio, Books, DCIM, Download, Images, LOST.DIR, Movies, Music, Notifications, Pictures, Podcasts, Ringtones, Video)

I'm using Android 4.1.2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are files created in "/storage/emulated/0" supposed to appear in "/storage/sdcard0"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173880/are-files-created-in-storage-emulated-0-supposed-to-appear-in-storage-sdcar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directory `/mnt` houses the mount points of different Android partitions. (hence the name mnt) Actually the "real" directory is `/mnt/sdcard`. `/sdcard` is a Symlink (short for Symbolic Link) to that directory, intended for easy of usability. (That is also explained  here [Are files created in "/storage/emulated/0" supposed to appear in "/storage/sdcard0"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/173880/131553%7D) and the answer by Izzy on that question is quite useful and detailed) It is possible to access `/mnt/sdcard` by ADB or a well designed file manager. `/sdcard` directory serves as a way for normal apps/users to interact with that data.

You can read more about Symlinks [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). [This article](https://www.all-things-android.com/content/understanding-android-file-hierarchy) (also the source of some facts I stated above) may be useful for a basic understanding about the Android filesystem. (It is/may be outdated for current Android versions, but you are using an old Android version, so it may still be useful for you)

Comment: Though I never can remember which is the original: `/mnt/sdcard` or `/storage/emulated/0` (or `/storage/sdcard0`? :)

Comment: I didn't find any source connecting /mint/sdcard to the other two directories, and for some reason I can't open /storage/emulated directory on my unrooted device. :D

Comment: No, that requires root. One is the original mount point (only accessible for root), one the the FUSE mount, one is the "convenience entry" for the user. I always lose track of which is which.