# Where is the music folder Android 2.3

Tags: music, file-system

I have a file exploring program, but I can't find the folder with my google play music.  I used google play to download music to my phone (not the SD).  I would like to transfer the music to my SD, but I can't find it on the phone's memory?  Which folder is it in?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Where does Google Music store offline songs?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/16220)