# Using Google Play music as an alarm

Tags: alarm, google-play-music

I downloaded a song from the Play Store to use as my alarm on my S3 but for some reason can't find it. When I go into Play Music it's there along with all my other downloaded music, but when I go into my alarm and try setting it it doesn't appear. Some of my other music appears, but not my music I've downloaded from the Play Store. Has anyone got a solution to this for me?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to download your music in MP3 format from Google Music through your PC and then put it on your phones SD-card. Then you should be able to set the MP3 as an alarm sound.

Answer (score 0):

When you download music from the Play Store, it stores it all on your account online. The best part of Google Music is that you can store up to 20,000 of your own songs online for free and then however many additional songs you purchase from the Play Store. These songs can be streamed at any time, or you can cache certain songs to listen to later when you don't have an internet connection or don't want to use all of your data. The downside to this is you never really have the music on your device.

Because of this, I am not sure you can use a song that you got from the Play Store as your alarm. You might be able to check in the file system to find where they are stored after they have been cached. Or you can download the song onto your computer, and then copy it manually onto the phone and then use it as an alarm.

**EDIT:** I have been looking all over my phone's file system trying to find where the offline music is being stored, but I have had no luck. Even after going to the location where every answer on this site says the offline music is stored, I still can't find the music. If you would like to check, [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16220/where-does-google-music-store-offline-songs) appears to work for most people finding the offline music. From there you should be able to set the offline music as your alarm.