# Where does Google Play Music v5 store music locally?

Tags: google-play-music

I know this question has been answered for older versions of the app, but where does the most recent app store offline music?

Clearly the mp3's I've selected are downloaded - because they play without an internet connection. But the default location for offline music is empty.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: do you have root?

Comment: New version of the app lets you choose external or internal storage. http://www.cultofandroid.com/46874/google-play-music-now-lets-you-specify-where-your-music-is-stored/

Comment: But the option only appears on devices with external storage/SD card.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does Google Music store offline songs?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16220/where-does-google-music-store-offline-songs)

Answer (score 3):

My Google Music 5.3.1317M.940995 running on a Nexus 4 with CM11 stores the mp3 files under

> `/data/data/com.google.android.music/files/music`

You need root to access that directory.

[A older version of Google Music on a Galaxy S stored it on the SD card.](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/16224/440) And, as I read in the official changelog, Google Music 5.x seems to be able to use the SD card as storage too. Which makes sense for devices with low internal storage space (`/data/data`).

Answer (score 0):

The issue of course is that it is root issue, if you are not rooted it is hidden from view.

The best way around it that I currently know is via the PC. Download and install the listen app for your PC, then you can download the music you have bought from the play store, and you can use the standard explorer to transfer to your music folder.

Which is how I deal with it and am able to use my preferred music player.
Only resort to listen when I want to listen to an album I haven't downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a lot of patience and a little bit of *unix wisdom this shouldn't too hard for you. Just open up a shell or connect using adb and try:

become root:

```
su
```

search for the song:

```
find / -name "*.mp3"
```