# Where are offline google music files stored on galaxy s6?

Tags: google-play-music

I have a galaxy s6 with many songs saved for offline use on google play music. I am having trouble finding the songs so that I can transfer them into the music storage file so that I can then transfer and listen to the songs on my galaxy gear s. Anyone have an idea of where these music files are or why I can't find them?

Comment: Even if you are able to find the music files they are encrypted using a private key and decrypted only while playing like when you are streaming it form the internet (if you use certain traffic counter app they will show that GPlay Music sends and receives a lot of data). They are usually inside the app's private storage, either on the internal storage or the external SD card.

Comment: Possibly covered in [Where does Google Play Music v5 store music locally?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51665/where-does-google-play-music-v5-store-music-locally)