# Is accessing Google Play Music subscription files legal?

Tags: rooting, google-play-music, streaming, offline

From [Where does Google Play Music v5 store music locally?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51665/where-does-google-play-music-v5-store-music-locally) I can see that if I am rooted, I can access the .mp3 files which I have downloaded to play offline from my Google Play Music subscription and move it to (say) my computer.

Now I know(?) that rooting is legal, but is retrieving music that I have downloaded to my Nexus 5 as part of my Play Music subscription also legal? I'm not planning on sharing the files, but only playing the music on my computer and home media player (which is not an Android TV).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct site to ask for legal advice. Maybe http://law.stackexchange.com is better?

Comment: Other than @GiantTree I'm pretty sure it is *not* the correct site, as our [help/on-topic] clearly states it as off-topic: *Legal questions.* In short, you could also ask whether circumventing DRM is legal. In both cases, answers might depend on what country you live in, and even considering that might be difficult to answer. The site GiantTree referred to might indeed be better suited – but check their `/help/on-topic` page first to make sure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about legal advice, which is explicitly stated off-topic by our [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3):

Form the Google Play [Terms of Use](https://play.google.com/about/play-terms.html)

> Capturing of Streams. You may not use Google Play or any Content in conjunction with any stream-ripping, stream capture or similar software to record or create a copy of any Content that is presented to you in streaming format.
>
> Sharing. You may not use Content as part of any service for sharing, lending or multi-person use, or for the purpose of any other institution, except as specifically permitted and only in the exact manner specified and enabled by Google (for example, through “Social Recommendations”).
>
> Security Features. You may not attempt to, nor assist, authorise or encourage others to circumvent, disable or defeat any of the security features or components, such as digital rights management software or encryption, that protect, obfuscate or otherwise restrict access to any Content or Google Play. If you violate any security feature, you may incur civil or criminal liability.