# How does one remove a single song from a downloaded album?

Tags: music, music-player, google-play-music

I have purchased an album on the play store and downloaded the entire album to my Android device, through the Play Music app. I want all of the songs from that album on my device, except for one.

1. If I click on the breadcrumbs icon next to the song, I can delete the song from my library, which will also remove it from my device, but I don't want it removed from my library. See the first image.
2. I can click on the downloaded icon below the album name, but that removes the entire album from the device. Refer to the second image.

How can I remove this one song? I have either missed something or this is quite awful software.

[image: Visual of Point 1] [image: Visual of Point 1]

Comment: Can you locate the songs on your storage with your explorer? If so, then you could be the way to go

Comment: @Beveloper Apparently you need root privilege to access it, https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51665/where-does-google-play-music-v5-store-music-locally.